# get string preg match between html tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

my html tag is `<div class="address"><h3>Vincent B. Davis</h3>` . I will grab Vincent B. Davis string. How i can get this? sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can do this without regex. I'd like to say use "strip_tags" for this one but it's better to use the DOMDocument instead of regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: You could use DOM parser: http://nimishprabhu.com/top-10-best-usage-examples-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html

Comment: can i use explode?

Comment: @JanuYoga, you may use anything. But the right, proper, valid and optimal way is using XML/HTML parsers

Comment: solved by using simple_html_dom thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking only about getting the regex:

```
preg_match("/<div class=\"address\"><h3>(.*)<\/h3>/", '<div class="address">
<h3>Vincent B. Davis</h3></div>', $output_array);

echo $output_array[1];
```